# Stored procedure : assign date if passed parameters are null

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to assign values to stored procedure when the passed arguments are null.

If startDate or endDate is null, I want to assign values to them

Like

```
@StartDate = '1990-01-01'
@EndDate = DATEADD(YEARS, 30, GETDATE()) -- 30 years from now.
```

How can I do this?

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetByProductID
(
    @ProductID INT,
    @StartDate DATETIME = NULL
    @EndDate DATETIME = NULL
)
AS
    SELECT ProductId, Name, InsertedDate, UpdatedDate
    FROM Products
    WHERE ProductId = @ProductID
      AND InsertedDate > @startDate
      AND UpdatedDate < @EndDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetByProductID
(
    @ProductID INT,
    @StartDate DATETIME = NULL
    @EndDate DATETIME = NULL
)
AS
    set @StartDate = coalesce(@StartDate,'1990-01-01')
    set @EndDate = coalesce(@EndDate,DATEADD(YEARS, 30, GETDATE())) -- 30 years from now.

    SELECT ProductId, Name, InsertedDate, UpdatedDate
    FROM Products
    WHERE ProductId = @ProductID
      AND InsertedDate > @startDate
      AND UpdatedDate < @EndDate
```

Comment: caolesce or isnull? which is more efficient?

Comment: they perform the same in most cases including here , read this article for more info https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/

Comment: Neither are likely more  efficient than the other, @Chatra . They are just *similar* functions.

Comment: When I try the above code, I'm getting error near the select query after set statement

Comment: @tejareddy ask a new question , provide code and full error message , I can't help you with no information about your problem